# core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'EventCreatePage'

Tags: angular, routes, ionic4

I am getting an error while navigating from one page to another. The error that I am getting is Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'EventCreatePage'

I have posted my .ts files below

I want to go from my homePage to my eventCreatePage

This is the routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/user/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'signup', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',canActivate: [AuthGuard], },
  { path: 'event-create/:id', loadChildren: './pages/event-create/event-create.module#EventCreatePageModule' ,canActivate: [AuthGuard],},
  { path: 'event-detail/:id', loadChildren: './pages/event-detail/event-detail.module#EventDetailPageModule',canActivate: [AuthGuard], },
  { path: 'event-list', loadChildren: './pages/event-list/event-list.module#EventListPageModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'profile', loadChildren: './pages/profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule' },
  { path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: './pages/reset-password/reset-password.module#ResetPasswordPageModule' },
  { path: 'signup', loadChildren: './pages/signup/signup.module#SignupPageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is my Home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database'; 
import { Quiz } from '../services/event/quiz.interface';
import { EventCreatePage } from '../pages/event-create/event-create.page'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  quiz= {} as Quiz;
  eventcreatePage = EventCreatePage;
  quiz$ : AngularFireList<Quiz>;

  constructor(private database : AngularFireDatabase,private router: Router){}



onclick(quiz: Quiz){
this.router.navigate(['EventCreatePage']);
}
}
```

and this is my home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { EventCreatePage } from '../pages/event-create/event-create.page';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      },

    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Comment: you should define EventCreatePage route like HomePage in RouterModule.

Comment: @FatemeFazli I tried that : I did as following 

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      },
      {
        path : '',
        component : EventCreatePage
      }
      
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage] 
}) and its giving me a new error that says that Event.create.page is not a part of any NgModule

Comment: i mean you have path  'event-create/:id' you can navigate it by something like  'event-create/123', for navigating to 'EventCreatePage' you should have something like ```{ path: 'EventCreatePage', loadChildren: './pages/event-create/event-create.module#EventCreatePageModule' ,canActivate: [AuthGuard],},``` in your routs.

Comment: @FatemeFazli I tried that but it still shows the same error. I tried navigating to the profile page but it gives the same error. stating that the " cannot match any routes.